# MVC5 agrupar datos con razor

Tags: sql, mvc, entity-framework, asp, razor

Hola necesito ayuda soy un novato en el tema pero se que tiene una forma sencilla de realizarse . 
En este caso estoy haciendo reporte de gastos e ingresos pero quiero agruparlos la categorai es decir que totalice solo gastos de la categoria y luego los gastos .

Pero en mi vista los totaliza todos los ingresos y luego todos los gastos de la categoria .

Como puedo modificar para que los separe de la siguiente forma :

despues del foreach coloque una validacion if donde separa la condicion de gastos y otra de ingresos no se si esto este perjudicando la agrupacion de la categoria 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
 listado = (from x in db.Workflow_Presupuesto(Mes, Anexo)
                                   orderby x.anexo
                                   select new PresupuestoCLS

                                   {   anexo=x.anexo,
                                       cdetallere = x.cdetallere,
                                       ccodianexo = x.ccodianexo,
                                       cdescripci = x.cdescripci,
                                       cdescuenta = x.cdescuenta,
                                       nmontpre = x.nmontpre,
                                       nmontrea = x.nmontrea,
                                       Variacion1 = x.nmontrea - x.nmontpre,
                                       ntotalpres = x.ntotalpres,
                                       realacumulado = x.ntotalreal + x.ntotalcomp,
                                       variacion2 = (x.ntotalreal + x.ntotalcomp) - x.ntotalpres

                                   }).ToList();
```

```html
    @foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.anexo))
    {

        if (item.cdescuenta == "INGRESOS")
        {


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.anexo)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cdescripci)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cdescuenta)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nmontpre)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nmontrea)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Variacion1)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ntotalpres)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.realacumulado)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.variacion2)</td>


            </tr>

            totalnmontpre += Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:N2}", item.nmontpre));
            totalnmontrea += Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:N2}", item.nmontrea));
            totalVariacion1 += Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:N2}", item.Variacion1));
            totalntotalpres += Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:N2}", item.ntotalpres));
            totalrealacumulado += Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:N2}", item.realacumulado));
            totalvariacion2 += Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:N2}", item.variacion2));
        }

    }



    <tr style="background-color:darkblue;color:aliceblue">
        <td colspan="1" align="center">
            <strong>Totales :</strong>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">
            <strong>Totales :</strong>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">
            <strong>@totalnmontpre</strong>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">
            <strong>@totalnmontrea</strong>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">
            <strong>@totalVariacion1</strong>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">
            <strong>@totalntotalpres</strong>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">
            <strong>@totalrealacumulado</strong>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">
            <strong>@totalvariacion2</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: hola Marcelo puedes agrupar los datos a nivel de una consulta bien sea sql o linq antes de exponerlas en la pagina mvc

Comment: Arriba coloque el controlador,como puedo hacer un group by en linq ?si lo hago igual a SQl me sale error